# Is the .probe line essential in a VCL file?

Tags: magento2, varnish

To make Varnish work, I need to remove this part:

```
.probe = {
    .url = "/pub/health_check.php";
    .timeout = 2s;
    .interval = 5s;
    .window = 10;
    .threshold = 5;
}
```

If I leave it, there is an Error 503 Backend fetch failed.

My configuration : Magento 2.3.3 - PHP 7.2 - Debian/Plesk - Varnish Docker